# how to upload a file in mapped drive using asp.net?

Tags: .net, iis

The application is video-streaming site. Its all in one server like application, uploaded videos and database. Now what i need is to split into two servers from one.The application and db on one server, then uploaded files on another server. So far i tried with UNC path to upload in different server but it doesn't work. Is there any permission access there in IIS? i have come across the article in Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/?id=257174. but its confusing. Is there any steps involved to to upload a file in mapped drive using asp.net? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a file in FileUpload control, you can simply save it anywhere, provided you have the permissions.

Just create a StreamWriter object and pass the n/w path to it.
Read the content from the Uploaded file and write them to the writer object.
Close the writer. It should work for you.

Your IIS User - under which your website is running should have the permissions to write on the n/w drive.